# QtMultimedia / GStreamer returning "Internal Data Stream Error" in PyQt playing audio

Tags: python, qt5, gstreamer, pyqt5, qtmultimedia

I'm trying to play an audio stream using PyQt5 + QtMultimedia, which in turn utilizes GStreamer. MP3 files play fine, but .OGG or .FLAC's do not.

When I run the following relevant snippet in my program:

```
self.mp = QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer(None)    
self.mp.setMedia(QtMultimedia.QMediaContent(QtCore.QUrl('http://archive.org/download/mogwai1999-10-16.flac16/mogwai1999-10-16d1t04.flac')))    
self.mp.play()
```

I get the following error back:

```
"Error: "Internal data stream error."
```

The same URL plays fine using gstream-launch in the command line, as well as other application, e.g. Amarok, VLC, Chrome. I've installed all of the various GST plugins, and the relevant bindings for Python.

What could be causing this error, or how can I get more information about the error in question?

GST log (verbose level 3):

```
0:00:00.014481056 32755 0x7f0b7c015f90 WARN     GST_ELEMENT_FACTORY gstelementfactory.c:456:gst_element_factory_make: no such element factory "vaapisink"!
0:00:00.015905265 32755 0x7f0b7c015f90 WARN     GST_ELEMENT_FACTORY gstelementfactory.c:456:gst_element_factory_make: no such element factory "vaapisink"!
0:00:01.750853131 32755 0x7f0b7c015f90 FIXME                    bin gstbin.c:4323:gst_bin_query: implement duration caching in GstBin again
0:00:01.967106715 32755 0x556c873c6ad0 WARN         audio-resampler audio-resampler.c:274:convert_taps_gint16_c: can't find exact taps
0:00:18.040756060 32755 0x7f0b50055e30 WARN         audio-resampler audio-resampler.c:274:convert_taps_gint16_c: can't find exact taps
0:00:19.056195960 32755 0x556c873c6ad0 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:2939:gst_base_src_loop:<source> error: Internal data stream error.
0:00:19.056219684 32755 0x556c873c6ad0 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:2939:gst_base_src_loop:<source> error: streaming stopped, reason error (-5)
Error: "Internal data stream error."
```

Comment: Try using the `GST_DEBUG` env-var - see [here](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer/html/gst-running.html) for details. (PS: debugging is usually enabled by default)

Comment: On the Qt side look at `QAudioDeviceInfo::supportedCodecs()`, maybe there are no Qt plugins loaded that call GStreamer's `oggdemux`, `vorbisdec`, `flacdec`, etc.

Comment: supportedCodec's gives me an empty list, but also wanted a parameter which I was surprised by (I may have called it wrong, I just passed a instance of AudioRole).

Comment: I am able to reproduce this problem on arch linux, using qt-5.9.1. The Qt media-player can stream all [these sample audio formats](http://techslides.com/sample-files-for-development) except for the ogg/flac ones. There is no problem If I download them and play them as local files, though. I also tested the same ogg/flac urls using `gst-launch`, and it plays them fine. So it is not a problem with my system setup or with gstreamer - it seems specific to Qt. However, a web-search has not yet produced any similar reports, so I'm not yet sure that this is a bug.

Comment: I'm really glad this isn't a one-off issue I'm experiencing, I've tried using the Pacaur Git versions of GStreamer with no luck either.